# What is the different between clustered, redundant, failover?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-server-2008, virtualization

when I'm trying to read document about new system structure i have some problem to understand the servers requirements like  the different between clustered, redundant, failover ?

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit vague, but for the three terms you gave:

Clustered: This means, at a basic level, that two or more servers are combined together to act as one in some way.  This may involve a computing cluster, such as in "grid" computing, where all the cluster nodes are computing a portion of the workload in order to scale the power of the system.  Alternatively (and more commonly), it may involve a failover cluster of nodes that are designed to take over for each other in the event that one (or more) fails.  In that case, a particular service only runs on a single node at a time, but may be moved to another when needed.

Redundant: Redundant nodes are those in a failover cluster, where they are designed to take over operations for one another in the event of the failure of one of the nodes.

Failover: The term for when services on one node "fail over" to another node in the event of an emergency, or when manually moved.

Answer (score 3):

In simplistic terms, this is what those terms mean to me.

- Clustered : a group of computers provide a service in a way that looks to the client like     a single computer.
- Redundant : using two computers when one would be sufficient. The redundant server is there in case the other computer fails.
- Failover : the automatic transfer of workload from a failed computer to another computer.

Answer (score 0):

From a client's point of view:

**Redundancy**: The client may see multiple options in raising a request. Multiple routes/servers. The client needs to be smart to choose an option. Any of the options should be able to provide the same consistent result. Ex:

- RAID is redundant storage so that a failed disk can be replaced.
- Redundant switches/routers in a network allow traffic to be routed over less congested available paths.

**Clustering**: Client wouldn't be aware that a set of redundant infrastructure(servers, databases, etc) is servicing their request. To the client it appears only as one interface/entity.

Both Redundancy and Clustering allow for **failover** which is just the request handled by an alternate/copy. In redundant systems, the client is aware of failover. In a clustered environment, the client isn't aware of it.